# drawing a sphere with opengl using the code from the redbook, but a different radius

Tags: opengl, geometry

I've read the codes in the redbook about drawing a sphere, but it is a unit sphere with radius=1. It starts from a icosahedron, an x and a z are defined to make the distances between all the 12 vertices and the center equal 1. So what if I need a larger or smaller sphere? I changed x and z proportionally, but it didn't work. How should I set the values of x and z to get a smaller sphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply scaling transform before drawing the sphere. If you are using fixed functionality pipeline you can do it using `glScalef(...)`. Otherwise you will have to construct the [scaling matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_%28geometry%29) yourself.

Comment: glScalef worked! Thank you! I can't imagine I didn't try that. However, lighting seems a little weird. So does it have any influence on lighting? When drawing a sphere I define normal vectors for all the vertices, so if I use glScalef, shouldn't I redefine all the normal vectors?

Comment: OK, I just find out I can use GL_NORMALIZE to automatically modify normal vectors. Thanks.

Comment: Scaling also affects normals so you should normalize them again after scaling. However OpenGL will do this for you if you call `glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)` before drawing.